# Object.entries() giving weird result in Node

Tags: node.js, object

This is in a Node method.
In the below code `dbResultsArr` is an array of objects.
Prior to reaching this block of code `dbResultsArr` gets assigned the array using a statement like `dbResultsArr = [...doc[result]];`

Inside the for loop when an element(`resultObj`) of `dbResultsArr` is consoled it shows an object. This is correct. Need to use these key value pairs to create a string(`myStr`). For this `Object.entries(resultObj)` is used.

However, console.log for `Object.entries(resultObj)` gives some different array. Can't figure out why?

```
          let ixi = 0;
          for(const r of dbResultsArr){
            ixi++

            const resultObj = new Object(r);
            // without this console.log('Object.entries(r)', Object.entries(r)); was not working
         
            if(ixi === 1) {
              // see output below
              console.log('r', resultObj);  
              console.log('Object.entries(resultObj)', Object.entries(resultObj));              
            }
  
            let resultsV2Obj = {
              searchType: searchType,
            };

            let myStr = '';
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(resultObj)) {
              
              if(ixi === 1) {
               // see output below
                console.log('key of r - ', `${key}`);
              }
  
              if(key === 'pan') {
                resultsV2Obj.pan = value;
                
              } else if(key !== '_id' && key !== '__v') {
                myStr += `${key}: ${value}; `
              }
            }
            resultsV2Obj.nameDetails = myStr;
            newCheckObj.pmlaCheckResultsV2.push(resultsV2Obj);
          }
```

console output:

```
r {
  _id: 610796d7cb5778deff3ef9bb,
  entity: 'Order in the matter of Infrastructures Limited and its Directors',
  name: 'Kumar Sharma',
  pan: 'xxxxx',
  orderDate: '02/11/2015\n\n\n03/10/2016',
  orderDetail: 'Restrained the entity from .....',
  __v: 0
}


Object.entries(resultObj) [
  [
    '__parentArray',
    [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  ],
  [ '__index', 0 ],
  [ '$isDocumentArrayElement', true ],
  [
    '$__',
    InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: undefined,
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      saving: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 610796d7cb5778deff3ef9bb,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      cachedRequired: {},
      session: null,
      '$setCalled': Set(0) {},
      ownerDocument: [Object],
      fullPath: 'sebiResultsFM',
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': [Object]
    }
  ],
  [ 'isNew', false ],
  [ 'errors', undefined ],
  [ '$locals', {} ],
  [ '$op', null ],
  [
    '_doc',
    {
      _id: 610796d7cb5778deff3ef9bb,
      entity: 'Order in the matter of Infrastructures Limited and its Directors',
      name: 'Kumar Sharma',
      pan: 'xxxxx',
      orderDate: '02/11/2015\n\n\n03/10/2016',
      orderDetail: 'Restrained the entity from .....',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  [ '$init', true ]
]


key of r -  __parentArray
key of r -  __index
key of r -  $isDocumentArrayElement
key of r -  $__
key of r -  isNew
key of r -  errors
key of r -  $locals
key of r -  $op
key of r -  _doc
key of r -  $init
```

expected result in myStr

```
entity: 'Order in the matter of Infrastructures Limited and its Directors'; name: 'Kumar Sharma'; orderDate: '02/11/2015\n\n\n03/10/2016'; orderDetail: 'Restrained the entity from .....'
```

Comment: thats' mongoose document class, so [use .lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) with mongoose queries instead to get plain JS objects

Comment: Thanks. I need Mongoose full Document as I am updating it later. So I modified my code to use the value of key "_doc", which is my required object and then applied another Object.entries() on it. ```for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(resultObj)) { if(key === '_doc') { for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(value)) { ....}}}``` .